# Add folder to sudo path without -i

Tags: path, sudo

There has been a lot of talk already done on Stack Overflow about adding a folder to the sudo path. But, none of the other tutorials I've seen have really answered the following question:

How can I add a folder to the sudo PATH without using -i.

Here is my setup. The folder I want to add is "/var/folder". There is the bash script "/var/folder/script.sh".  I added the following lines of code to the /root/.bashrc file:

```
if [ -d /var/folder ]; then
    PATH=/var/folder:$PATH
fi
```

Now, when I type in the command "sudo echo $PATH" I get the following output:

```
/var/folder:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

The problem is, when I run the command "sudo script.sh", the script can't seem to be found. The output is as follows:

sudo: script.sh: command not found

This is in spite of the fact that tab-auto-complete works on "sudo script.sh".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All though the $PATH is defined when you do an echo of it, for running the script it is not actually defined.  So to see what is happening, you can run the following:

```
sudo -s
echo $PATH
```

You will notice that it will be:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

**Where is it getting the $PATH from?**

It is defined in your sudoers file:

> Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

**Solution**

You can update the Defaults secure_path in the sudoers file to have the correct value.

```
Defaults        secure_path="/var/folder:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

---

Going back to how you were seeing the correct value when you ran:

```
sudo echo $PATH
```

Since you had $PATH defined with /var/folder before you ran that command, it just replaced the $PATH with the value, but your actual path for sudo was

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

so you were effectively running

```
sudo echo /var/folder:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```